# Shell script to delete files and folders that don't exist in another folder

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

Using a shell script I wish to delete all files and folders from `/folder2/` that do not exist in `/folder1/`. Files only need to be matched by name.

I must add that the content of both folders shouldn't necessarily match after this operation because it's possible that `/folder1/` contains files that do not in exist in `/folder2/`. So after executing the shell script all files and folders found in `/folder2/` can also be found in `/folder1/` but not vice versa.

Comment: How are you defining the files being "the same"? Is it sufficient that their names match, or are you looking to compare the contents of the files?

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:
`rsync -r --delete --existing --ignore-existing /path/to/folder1/ /path/to/folder2/`

rsync will delete all files and folders from folder2 that are not found in folder1 recursively. Also, rsync will skip creating files on the destination. This answer was found here: https://serverfault.com/a/713577